# Declaring an App is Only for Handsets

Tags: android, google-play

I have designed my application only for handset ,i need it should not allow tablet to download the app.i have used like this:

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

It is downloadable to handset but while i try to download the app in galaxy s3 handset,i am getting the message like the app is not compatible with your device.

Could somebody help me..@thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: In my opinion restricting installation is the wrong solution. Either fix the layouts or just live with the fact that it won't be perfect on all devices.

Comment: @laalto but how could i fix that issue....

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the specific problem but http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html is a good starting point.

Comment: @laalto actually i have designed the app.the app is looking correctly in normal screen but in 7" and 10" screen the images are streching not looking nice..for fixing that i have to use different layout like layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp,without using that..is there any other way

Answer (score 4):

this will be helpful to you.

```
<supports-screens 
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320"
        android:largestWidthLimitDp="600" />
```

here we specify smallest width and largest width of divvice that our application support.google play filters the devices that does not match criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you :

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="false"
android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

Comment: I need my app should be able to download in galaxy s3 handset but not in tablet

Comment: Yes I know. Galaxy S3 device size is NORMAL and screen density is XHDPI. So I this this can help you.

Comment: i have one more doubt that in android large screen and xlarge screen what are all the screen resolution will occupy

Comment: Its depend upon their DPI and Screen size. 
Generally 
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).